# How to Use Nested ObservableCollections to Fill Data Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, observablecollection

I currently have several ObservableCollections nested inside of single ObservableCollection. When I try to bind this to the DataGrid however, it shows a single column that says "Count" and has the length of each Observable Collection in each row. Is there a solution for this?

Edit:
XAML Binding: ItemsSource="{Binding Data}"
"Data" is an ObservableCollection of ObservableCollections in the ViewModel.

Comment: What would be the business logic behind nested ObservableCollection ?

Comment: How are you doing the binding?  via itemsource in codebehind?

Comment: Try to make your class nested instead of ObservableCollection.

Comment: I am not binding through codebehind, as I am trying to use MVVM. I have a binding to the ObservableCollection<ObservableColelction<>> in the XAML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply refer to one of the nested ObservableCollections.

If you wanted the first one for instance.

```
var first = instanceObservable.First();

dataGridInstance.ItemSource = first;
```

Comment: This does not work for me for two reasons. 1) I am using MVVM so no codebehind and 2) I want to have each ObservableCollection represent a row and have all the collections represented.

Comment: @Kyle Could you show the xaml you are using to bind .. the more details you provide, the closer to a solution you'll get.

Comment: Sure. I editted my original post as well, but: XAML Binding: ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" , where "Data" is an ObservableCollection of ObservableCollections in the ViewModel.

Comment: @Kyle From you explanations .. you DON'T need an observablecollection of observablecollections .. what you need is a model that will now be the type of the observablecollection. Are the data in the rows identical in structure?

Comment: My nested ObservableCollections have the type of my Model, which has one field of type String. The thing is, I wanted each ObservableCollection<Model> to be a row, and put them into another ObservableCollection that would hold them all.

Comment: @Kyle You don't have to do that .. simply create one and add instances of the Model to a single ObservableCollection... very much like using a List<T> or any other Collection.

Comment: When I just have a long ObservableCollection, it is represented as one column though, and the problem is that I can't hard-code columns in the View because I am dynamically loading in spreadsheets that have different formats.

Comment: @Kyle If you need multiple columns and your Model has just one field .. that means you probably need a new model and code to take all this data and merge them into the new model BEFORE adding to an ObservableCollection.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Thank you.